# Finding records across time zones using active record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, timezone

I'm developing an app where a user can request that an email be sent to them at a specific time every day in their timezone.
For example User A lives in London and schedules an email at 2pm every day London time and User B lives in New York and schedules an email at 2pm New York time.

I'm wondering how I should store my schedule timestamps in my database and what supporting information I need to store along side this to support the fact that all times depend on a specific timezone.

I'm thinking that storing the timestamps as utc with a separate column for the timezone is the way to go but I'm unsure of how to query the database to return all scheduled emails at a specific time without having to perform one query per timezone.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, store the data in UTC - rails will do this by default; put a `time_zone` column on your User model

Here is a post I wrote for timezones in rails which you might find helpful: http://jessehouse.com/blog/2013/11/15/working-with-timezones-and-ruby-on-rails/

This might be overly complicated, but I am thinking if you had a background job running (delayed_job, sidekiq, etc) it would check each timezone/email schedule - something like this (You definitely want time_zone on your User, maybe on the schedule as well?)

```
# loop through all timezones
ActiveSupport::TimeZone.zones_map(&:name).each do |time_zone|
  # get a list of any saved schedules in this timezone
  scheduled_in_zone = EmailSchedule.where(time_zone: time_zone)

  # execute block in that timezone
  Time.use_zone(time_zone) do 
    # Time.current is timezone aware (same as Time.zone.now)
    now = Time.current

    scheduled_in_zone.each do |scheduled|
      if scheduled.deliver_at <= now 
        scheduled.deliver_it!        
      end
    end
  end
end
```

I also recommend checking out: http://railscasts.com/episodes/106-time-zones-revised

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I didn't know about the use_zone block, that's really handy! The one thing I want to avoid with this is having to run multiple queries. This would get very painful as the table size grows. I would love to be able to run one query that asks for all all emails to be sent at this time, and it would magically figure it out across all the timezones. I'm thinking there may not be a way to accomplish this with active record but instead I may have to drop down to using the timezone support in postgres and try to accomplish it there.

Comment: You could also have 1 background job per timezone and run them all at the same time; if you keep the timezone handling in rails you won't need to worry about day light savings offsets